# JQuery Autocomplete response HTML rendering issue in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Need help please. I have jquery+autocomplete working fine on home page but on listing pages of my site, the browser is not able to render the HTML properly and not showing up correctly. This somehow works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but misbehaves quite often, and cannot get it to work in Chrome (fails always), IE (most of the time), Firefox (works often, but fails).

Page url: http://www.schoolswelike.com/tag/state/nct-of-delhi

Browser versions it's failing:
Version 40.0.2214.115 m, IE 9

HTML Page Script:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#jqkeywords").autocomplete({
        source: "/autocomplete_filter.php",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var url = ui.item.alias;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = '/someurl/' + ui.item.id + '-' + url;
            }
        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#jqkeywords_label").html("No results found! Try another keyword to search within results:");
            }
        },
        html: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here. What do you mean by "fail"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I wish I could attach a screen here :( got low rating so it wont allow me. By fail I mean, the result set should come out in formatted HTML and vertical scroll bar, but this page shows each result line item with raw HTML formatting (i can see <b> and other HTML tags) and it is non-clickable.

Comment: When the page opens, try the search on page under text "Type title/name/city/state to search within results" - thats jquery search and got issues.